# Phonegap get screen height of working area (screen less the status bar)

Tags: android, cordova, screen-size

I am using windows.innerHeight but it seems this includes the status bar of the device.

Is there another window call where it does not include status bar or is there a way to get status bar height then use jquery to set style of the body?

Any tips or way to do this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm use

```
$(window).height()
```

which is ~ equal

```
window.innerHeight
```

but it's work for me when page fully loaded on Android and iOS.

[Sample here](http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/jquery-mobile-full-height-content.html)